# cannot convert dynamically loaded textarea to tinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, tinymce

I have a jQuery modal dialog, which is loaded by AJAX call. There is one textarea, however I cannot convert it to tinyMCE editor.

tried

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'Text')

 $('textarea').tinymce(...)
```

all works great if textarea is created from normal call.
(I suspect there is something about DOM)

Comment: If I try to set ().html(strinq) and string comes from static place all is ok, however then i try load string, that i got from ajax call nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz call

```
$('textarea').tinymce(...)
```

after you add textarea to the DOM hierarchy

Comment: Most of comments that I found - is that it needs to be removed properly to use it again, hover I cannot get it to work for first time :(

Comment: have u noticed in firbug. it may give you some idea about what goes wrong

Comment: `function EditNews(id) {
        $.post('/Adm/NewsEditor', { ID: id }, function (data) {
            $('#NewsEditor').html(data);
            $("#NewsEditor").dialog("open");
        });
    }`

Comment: Hmm for some reason - only change `$('textarea').tinymce(...)` does to textarea, it sets it hidden instead of adding helper element

Comment: function is clean. may be there is something wrong on server side

Comment: Just noticed that tinyMCE makes it`s own call when I post to server. Is it possible to disable it?

Comment: Unfortunate human error that took me 6h :(
Didn`t spot, that I left one line uncomented.

Comment: Unfortunate human error that took me 6h :(
Didn`t spot, that I left one line uncomented.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and it turns out that it was because I was loading the tinymce script through yepnope.  When I put it directly on the page, the `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'id');` worked.  Also, make sure you copy all of the files downloaded (including the 'lang' folder and the 'themes' folder) into the same directory as your tiny_mce.js file.